# If mouse button is up but not on this gameObject

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

How can i check in script if mouseUp but not on this gameObject?

```
void OnMouseUp()
```

Only works when mouse is on gameObject, is there other function for opposite?

Comment: Please provide more detail about what you want to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0)](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.GetMouseButtonUp.html) is what you're looking for.

You'll need to check for it each `Update` call though, it's not an event.

Comment: There is no such thing as `Input.GetMouseUp` in Unity

Comment: I recommend using [`GetButtonUp()`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.GetButtonUp.html) instead, as it allows the button in question to be rebound by the user.

Answer (score 0):

Cast a ray on mouse up and check for collision with your object.
Your object will need a collider and be tagged with "yourObjectTag" for the example to work.

```
Update()
{
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0))
    {
        RaycastHit hit;

         if (Physics.Raycast(Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition), Vector3.forward, out hit))
         {
             if (hit.collider != null && hit.collider.tag != "yourObjectTag")
                // do stuff here
         }
    }
}
```